# UISearchBar Scope empty space

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, uisearchbar

I have `UISearchController` in my application:

```
-(void)setSearchBar {
    self.resultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.resultsController.tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.self forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchTitleCell"];
    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsController];
    [self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:self];
    [self.searchController setDelegate:self];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.1")) {
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    }

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;

    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.definesPresentationContext = true;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;

    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"One", @"two", @"three"];
}
```

And I want to add Scopebar when the `UISearchBar` bar is clicked and hide it when I exit the `UISearchBar`, so I use this code:

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}

- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

The problem is that when I close the `UISearchBar`(by clicking the cancel button) I still can see the scope empty space.

Before(When searchbar is clicked):
[image]

After(After clicking the searchbar cancel btn):
[image]

Any idea of how I can fix this problem?

Comment: can you explain more what you actually want to do.
you want to hide the search bar on cancel button or you want to hide the search bar image.

Comment: @VipinPareek I want to hide the hide the Searchbar scopebar

Comment: create a outlet of your search bar and then when you click on cancel button just right the code for hide search bar like that
yoursearchbar_object_name.ishidden = true and when you want to show the search bar again you write the code like that yoursearchbar_object_name.ishidden = false

Comment: @VipinPareek the Searchbar scope is hidden, buts leaves an empty space

Comment: then add a outlet of your searchbar height constraints when you hide the searchbar then you will write one line code also like that
search_bar_height_constraints_object_name.constant = 0 // this line is written where you hide the search bar 

when you show the searchbar then write the  
search_bar_height_constraints_object_name.constant = your actuall search bar height like 40.
and your space is gone.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Solution that will work for me related to SearchBar Height When we added the Scope Bar buttons as well for iOS 13.

1. Implement - UISearchControllerDelegate Or UISearchBar Delegate and assign as below.

   searchController.delegate = self;
   searchController.SearchBar.delegate = self;
2. Override UISearchControllerDelegate Or Override UISearchBarDelegate methods.

   -(void) didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
   [self resizeTableViewHeaderHeight];
   }
   -(void) didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
   [self resizeTableViewHeaderHeight];
   }

   -(void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
   {
   [self resizeTableViewHeaderHeight];
   }
3. Resize TableView header height depending on the search bar height -

   -(void)resizeTableViewHeaderHeight {

   ```
    UIView *headerView = self.table_view.tableHeaderView;
    CGRect frame = headerView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 56; //Make Constant and assign value to it.
    headerView.frame = frame;
    self.table_view.tableHeaderView = headerView;
   ```

   }